# Do browsers run PHP scripts without my input?

Tags: php, browser

I have a PHP script that I run to update a database of mine - it is held on a remote webserver, so I make changes to that PHP script and then run it to dump the results into the database.  It works fine - except I have been noticing that the PHP script is running when I don't want it to.

That is - when I DO NOT type in the URL with the specific GET variables required for it to work, the script seems to be running anyways.  So my question is do browsers request URLs without me asking them to?

The problem is the script takes a very long time to run and it seems when the requests (from some other source) are run that it doesn't complete - which leaves my database only partially full and effectively useless.  What I have noticed, however, is that it is only the one set of tables from a specific request that I have been running that are getting "randomly" run.

EDIT:
I have a script that requires multiple variables be passed to it through GET.  I will run it at one point in the day (say 2pm) it takes a very long time to complete, almost 2 hours.  It completes fine and all is good.  Then a few hours later, WITH NO INPUT FROM ME, it runs again - with the exact same variables passed to it but does not complete.

My suspicion is that my browser is re-requesting the URL for some reason, or Google is or something, I'm just looking to see if anyone has any idea what could be causing this.

EDIT 2:
Realized I'm an idiot.  What's happening is my computer goes to sleep and when it wakes up the browser refreshes instead of using the stale data.

Comment: Re-reading this I am not being as clear as I could be.  I have a php script that I run (mostly through Google Chrome) that is executed by going to mywebaddress/myscript.php?token=mytoken&var1=table1&var2=table2 etc.  It works perfectly fine - except that the exact same URL seems to be being sent or executed when I don't want it to.  I'm wondering if it is something Chrome (or my ISP or any browser) is doing by going to URLs I have previously typed in.

Comment: What is the question here? Also where is the script you are referring to?

Comment: sure my browser goes off and downloads porn when I'm not looking

Comment: The script itself is like 150kb and not really the issue.  There are no time calls in it, no javascript, etc.  The question is just what could be causing the script to run WITHOUT input from me?  It requires specific variables to be passed to it to work, and it's always the same variables I passed to it earlier in the day and it just runs again without my input.

Comment: the access logs will tell you what exactly 'hit' the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are run without input on a browser if you:

1. include javascript timeout to refresh/reload the page
2. basically write code inside the script to call itself whether one time, a few times, or at intervals
3. your browser is not "normal", due to whatever reason
4. a malware on you machine grabs the url from the browser and forces the browser to call it again and again
5. etc

Comment: 6. Your computer goes to sleep and the browser refreshes when it wakes up.